# how to get range in excel sheet using openxml and c#

Tags: c#, excel, c#-4.0

I have to read Excel(.xlsx) file. I am using OpenXML NuGet pkg.
I am trying to get the range(`xlRange`), so I can fetch the data from a particular cell. But not getting success. This code is created in console environment.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{    
    bool flagDataError = false;
    string sDuplicateRows = string.Empty;
    string sCreatedRows = string.Empty;
    string sFileTypeError = string.Empty;
    string filepath = @"C:\test.xlsx";
    var fileName = Path.GetFileName(filepath);
    var fileExtension = Path.GetExtension(filepath);
    if ((fileExtension != ".xlsx") && (fileExtension != ".xls"))
        sFileTypeError = "Invalid file. \n\nPlease browse a correct Excel file to upload.";
    else
    {          
        using (SpreadsheetDocument doc = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(filepath, false))
        {
            WorkbookPart workbookPart = doc.WorkbookPart;
            WorksheetPart worksheetPart = workbookPart.WorksheetParts.First();
            SheetData sheetData = worksheetPart.Worksheet.Elements<SheetData>().First();


            List<AxisData> data = new List<AxisData>();
            for (int i = 5; i <= 16; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 2; j <= 13; j++)
                {
                    AxisData axisDetails = new AxisData();
                    axisDetails.ProductCode = "AXIS " + xlRange.Cells[i, 1].Value;
                    axisDetails.ContractPeriod = Convert.ToDateTime(xlRange.Cells[4, j].Value);
                    axisDetails.SettlePrice = Convert.ToDecimal(xlRange.Cells[i, j].Value);
                    axisDetails.EffectiveStartDate = efectiveStartDate;
                }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "not getting success"? Are you getting an error? How is the program not behaving like you want it to? Be specific when describing your issues. Also, the code you've provided has mismatched curly braces.

Answer (score 0):

```
IEnumerable<Row> ShRows = sheetData.Elements<Row>();

var _RCount = SHRows.Count();
```